# aspectJ JoinPoint и рефакторинг

Tags: java, aspectj

Хочу в совете aspectJ получать входные данные отслеживаемого метода. Способ, который я знаю, описан ниже.

```
@Aspect
public aspect Asp {

    @After("execution(private void ru.test.test(..))")
    public void test(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        Object[] objectArr = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String str = (String) objectArr[0];
        //...
    }

}
```

Но данный способ полх в случае рефакторинга отслеживаемого кода. Если поменять число входных параметров или их тип, то придется вручную менять их и в аспекте.

Есть ли иной способ получать в аспекте входные параметры отслеживаемой функции?

Comment: что вам запрещает пробегаться циклом по аргументам?

Comment: Да можно и циклом, но приводить их потом надо будет явно в любом случае. В примере String, но допустим поменяли его на Integer. Придется вручную менять код и в аспекте. Средства среды разработки не поменяют его автоматом при рефакторинге.

Comment: А не нужно их приводить, работайте как с Object

Comment: При реализации аспектов aspectj используя java-байндинги это сделать нельзя. Практичный выход из этой ситуации, это интеграционный тест, который будет проверять, что ваш аспект можно применить и он успешно вызывается. В случае рефакторинга, такой тест покажет, что аспект перестал работать.

Comment: Альтернатива - это писать аспекты на языке AspectJ и пользоваться компилятором ajc. Но по-моему, смысла особого нет. Разрабатывать не так удобно (не во всех IDE есть поддержка), тесты все равно нужно писать и в java это проще и практичней.